# Function that puts zero after a certain decimal in every element of the matrix

Tags: machine-precision

We know that in Mathematica there is some default precision, which you can also change. This means, that after a certain decimal(fixed by the precision), the computer puts pseudo random numbers.
I am looking for a function F that would put everything zero after a certain decimal. Let us say I want this to be the fourth decimal, then

F[0.12345678]=0.12340000

Does such function exist?

Thank you

Comment: Floor[0.12345678, 0.0001] gives 0.1234 and if you want 4 zeros to the right you can use NumberForm[Floor[0.12345678, 0.0001],{4,8}]

Comment: @tchronis thanks great, and can you think of something equivalent for matrices? You can use it for a matrix, but I have realized that after you use it with matrix, Mathematica does not consider it a matrix any more, for example you can do Eigensystem afterwards

Comment: Thanks @Mencia , you can apply Floor to the matrix. I suppose you have rectangular Matrices. Floor[matrix,0.0001] works in my machine. And for nice output you can apply the NumberForm function.

Comment: @tchronis great man, that is exactly what I needed, appreciate!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two approaches (trying to emulate the fomratting it just the truncation):

```
f[x_, n_] := N[IntegerPart[10^n x]/10^n, StringLength@ToString@x]
```

or

```
g[x_, n_] := N[Floor[10^n x]/10^n, StringLength@ToString@x]
```

Evaluating:

```
f[0.12345678,4]

g[0.12345678,4]
```

yield:

0.12340000